# Prove $ \lim_{n \to \infty} \int_a^b \left (1+\frac x n \right)^ne^{-x} dx = b-a $

Tags: real-analysis, uniform-continuity

So I know if you let $f_n(x) = \left(1+\frac x n \right)^ne^{-x}$, then $f(x) = e^{x}\cdot e^{-x} = 1$

Thus, the integral from $\int_a^b dx$ = $b-a$.  I'm confused about how we know $f_n$ is uniformly continuous.

Comment: I hope I didn't make any mistake in edit. Also learn same [latex](http://www.codecogs.com/latex/eqneditor.php).

Comment: $e^{-x}$ is uniformly continuous, as is $\lim_{n\to\infty}f_n(x)$,

Answer (score 3):

Over any bounded subset, $(1+n^{-1}x)^n\to e^x$ uniformly.

Comment: Thank you! Why is that so?

Comment: @AmandaLarento It suffices you show convergence is uniform over $[-M,M]$ for any $M>0$, and then take $M$ large enough to get the bounded set inside.

Comment: Thank you, that is helpful.

Comment: @AmandaLarento As a further hint, you may use the Taylor series around zero, of order $n$, call them $g_n$; and that power $f_n$. You know $g_n\to e^x$ uniformly over $[-M,M]$ (this is standard) and then show that $\lVert f_n-g_n\rVert_\infty\to 0$.